# Strange behavior of .Contains in Azure api management

Tags: c#, azure-api-management

I'm facing this strange behavior in Azure API Management and am looking for a workaround.

```
<set-variable name="isIOS" value="@(context.Request.Headers["User-Agent"].Contains("iOS"))" />
```

is always false, unless there is an exact match and the User-Agent value is exactly "iOS".

If it contains the full string (in my case) "iOS Agent - xxxxx/1.2.4 (com.xxxxx.yyyyy.zz; build:108; iOS 14.3.0) Alamofire/4.9.1" isIOS gets set "false".

Can somebody confirm this behavior and/or knows a workaround for this?

Comment: That should be by design - most likely your code is .net core and you are accessing https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iheaderdictionary...  Could you please [edit] post to clarify what is type of `Headers` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`context.Request.Headers` in Azure API Management policy its a simple `IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string[]>`

Take a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-policy-expressions#ref-context-request

In your case you can just get the `isIOS` variable like this:

```
<set-variable name="isIOS" value="@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("User-Agent","").Contains("iOS"))" />
```

This approach is also recommended by Microsoft and prevent throwing exceptions like `KeyNotFoundException`